# Disabled preview in First Spirit by e-spirit

Tags: content-management-system

As a content editor- using First Spirit, the CMS by e-spirit, I want to be able to disable the preview pane so that it will run faster and unlocking my content is easier. And general tips on how to speed up displaying a module is also very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the integrated preview per user via the menu: view -> integrated preview. Deselect both options. As a project administrator, you can disable the preview pane per project. Open the ServerManager, open the project and go "client applications". Disable the integrated preview content/media options.

General tips to speed up the client (note sure what a module is in this context):
- You can switch from HTTP to Socket communication
- Using more RAM for the JavaClient can help if you use the client a lot
- General JVM tuning of the FirstSpirit-Server may help if all editors are experiencing a slow-down

You should contact the FirstSpirit Support if you need concrete advice.

Answer (score 1):

Christoph's answer is correct.

Additional, try FirstSpirit's ContentCreater (was: WebEdit). From FirstSpirit 5 on it is easy to implement and makes the life for editors much easier. It is very fast, faster as the JAVA Client can ever be in my opinion.

To implement it take a wrapping element like a  and add 
`$CMS_VALUE(editorId())$`

Like:

```
<div class="wrapper" $CMS_VALUE(editorId())$>
   <h1>$CMS_VALUE(headline)$</h1>
   <p>$CMS_VALUE(text)$</p>
   <img src="$CMS_REF(image)$" alt="$CMS_VALUE(alttext)$" />
</div>
```

This will give the editors already all the form elements of the JAVA Client inside a wysiwyg Editor.